# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

i'm receiving the following errors, very new to iphone dev and objective C. I am very much willing to send over my project for someone to have a look, i'm running in circles and have no idea what to do next!

```
2010-11-10 19:38:07.822 iShisha[2698:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x025f9b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0274940e objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x025ef695 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
 3   iShisha                             0x00003dc5 -[MapViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1262
 4   UIKit                               0x0032dd6f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 619
 5   UIKit                               0x00323e02 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
 6   UIKit                               0x00338774 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
 7   UIKit                               0x003307ec -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
 8   QuartzCore                          0x046d7481 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
 9   QuartzCore                          0x046d71b1 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
 10  QuartzCore                          0x046d02e0 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 302
 11  QuartzCore                          0x046d0040 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
 12  QuartzCore                          0x04700ebb _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
 13  CoreFoundation                      0x025daf4b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x0256fb27 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x02538ce7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x02538350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x02538271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 18  GraphicsServices                    0x02ed800c GSEventRunModal + 217
 19  GraphicsServices                    0x02ed80d1 GSEventRun + 115
 20  UIKit                               0x002caaf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
 21  iShisha                             0x00001de8 main + 102
 22  iShisha                             0x00001d79 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

[Session started at 2010-11-10 19:38:15 +0000.]
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""MapViewController.m":204" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - ""MapViewController.m":317" resolved
Pending breakpoint 3 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please post the code inside of [MapViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In CocoaTouch, tables have a delegate and a data source.  The delegate sends and receives messages for the table view, and the data source controls the information that goes in the table and the table's headers and footers.  The data source tells the table how many rows to draw, how many sections, what to put as the section titles, etcetera.

The table view queries the data source for how many rows to draw via the

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

method.  Then, in the

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, the tableView asks for a cell to populate the table from the data source.  When programming for the iPhone, tables are mostly populated by an array, a single variable (object) that contains many other variables (objects).  You tell an array what object you want, by asking

```
object = [array objectAtIndex:INTEGER]; //where INTEGER is an unsigned (zero or greater, no minus)
```

what happened, is that your data source is expecting X number of objects for the table, and there are X-Y available.  If it thinks there are 10, but there are only 9, when the table asks for the 10th object, you get a crash because there is no object to give.

look in your code for hte line

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

and see what that code is.  Chances are you're providing the wrong data there.

Good luck

Comment: This is brilliant! What happens if i need more rows in one section than another, for example, i needed 6 rows in one and only 1 in another

Comment: simple: if (section == 0) { return 5;} else if (section == 1) {return 3;}  this code will give section 0 (first section) 5 rows, and section 1 (2nd section) 3 rows

Comment: Great explanation. I found my problem was that my TableView was using `Static Cells` (which was set in IB). I changed it to `Dynamic Prototypes` and that way it isn't limited to a static amount of cells. I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a need to change from static to dynamic cells for this one (there are cases where you may need the cells to be static). What may have caused this problem is that you may have only named 0 sections for your table view in the "Attributes Inspector" section in the storyboard. All you need to do is increase this number to 1 or as many sections as you may need.

Well I think that's what @styfle's problem was.