# Issue with scrolling tableview with customized tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, tableview, uitableview

my problem is that I have a complex structure (`NSArray`s and `NSDictionaries`) and when I try to customize the appearance of my table view cells, I build an `NSArray` using the complex structure that I said above. First of all, there is no problem when it shows the `UITableview` (with the cells), but then, when I scroll (down or up), my app gets an error like those ones:

(this is when I scroll down)

```
[8721:40b]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:  -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

(this is when I scroll down)

```
[9018:40b] -[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c59750

2011-03-01 17:51:23.447 CinePlanet[9018:40b]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[__NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c59750
```

I have been very careful on building my `NSArray`, and I don't know if I am omitting something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear me there is something wrong with the construction of NSArray. i do'nt want to repeat again because the same problem discussed here,

suggest you to look in the below post.

[Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148395/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsrangeexception-reason-nsmu)